# Maximum principle for heat equation in Brezis' Book

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

In Brezis' book, look at the maximum principle for the heat equation in $\Omega \times (0,T)$ where $\Omega$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$:
$$u_{t}-\Delta u=0$$
$$ (x,t) \in \Omega \times (0,T)$$
$$u=0  \in \partial \Omega.$$
He proves that:
$$
\max _{\overline{\Omega} \times[0, T]} u=\max _P u
$$
where $P=(\overline{\Omega} \times\{0\}) \cup(\Gamma \times[0, T])$ is called the *parabolic boundary* of the cylinder $\Omega \times(0, T)$.

He sets $$v(t,x)=u(x,t)+\epsilon \lvert x\rvert^{2}$$  and he supposes that there is $(a,b)\notin P$ such that:
$$
\max _{\overline{\Omega} \times[0, T]}v=v(a,b)
$$
and if $b=T$
$$\partial_{t}v(a,b)\geq 0 \tag{1}$$ and if $b<T$ then $$\partial_{t}v(a,b)=0. \tag{2}$$

**Question:** I don't see why we have $(1)$ and $(2)$. I tried to use the definition of the derivative using limits but I just get that the derivate is non-negative? Thanks.

*Reference:*
Brezis, H., & Brézis, H. (2011). Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations (Vol. 2, No. 3, p. 5). New York: Springer.

Answer (score 1):

By assumption, the function $f\colon[0,T]\to\mathbb R,\,t\mapsto v(a,t)$ has a global maximum in $t=b$. Thus $f(b)\geq f(b-h)$ for all $h\geq 0$, which implies
$$
\lim_{h\searrow 0}\frac{f(b)-f(b-h)}h\geq 0.
$$
Hence $\partial_t f(b)\geq 0$ (note that $b=0$ is not possible if $(a,b\notin P$, hence $b-h\in [0,T]$ for sufficiently small $h$).

If $b<T$, you can also take the limit from the right side to conclude $\partial_t f(b)=0$.

Comment: thanks MaoWao  ,what i understand is that  in the case $b<T$ we have that $f(T+h)=f(T)$ but why?

Comment: I don't understand why you think that's true.

Comment: $\partial_{t}f(b)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}$ so $\partial_{t}f(b)=0$  because $f(b+h)=f(b)$ in the case $b<T$ right MaoWao?

Comment: No. In the case $b<T$ you have $f(b\pm h)-f(b)\leq 0$. Thus the left-sided limit is nonnegative and the right-sided limit is nonpositive, which means that the limit (if it exists) is $0$.

Comment: Thank you i aprreciate your help